# Why is ref always null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component below, at the first render I have the correct `ref` to input, but then I always get `null`, with the next render, please tell me why? `ref` is passed on through props to input:

```
const inputRef = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
        inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  });
 }, [inputRef]);

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <FirstComponent />
      {({ selectedItem, items }) => (
             <SecondCompontnt
                inputRef={inputRef}
                items={items}
                onSelect={onSelect}
                value={selectedItem}
              />
          )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is not reproducible, the value of inputRef is always going to be null in the code you have provided, you give the ref the value of null...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have the `ref` in the parent component for one of its children then you need to apply so called [Forwarding Ref technique](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html), as the documentation states:

> Ref forwarding is a technique for automatically passing a ref through a component to one of its children. This is typically not necessary for most components in the application.

Let's say you have in the parent component as the following:

```
const childDivRef = useRef(null);

return <>
  <ChildComponent ref={childDivRef} />
</>
```

Then you need to have in the child component as below:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

const ChildComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <div ref={ref} className="child-component">
        <h3>Child component</h3>
    </div>
})
```

If you need a working example, please find this GitHub repository what I made earlier: https://github.com/norbitrial/react-forwarding-ref-example

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: @Blackbonny Anytime. If the solution works for you, please consider accepting as the answer for your question, thank you!